Does a Battlerager Grapple count as an attack for the purposes of damage resistance/immunities?

Battlerager Armor SCAG p121
When you choose this path at 3rd level, you gain the ability to use
spiked armor as a weapon.
While you are wearing spiked armor and are raging, you can use a bonus
action to make one melee weapon attack with your armor spikes at a
target within 5 feet of you. If the attack hits, the spikes deal 1d4
piercing damage. You use your Strength modifier for the attack and
damage rolls.
Additionally, when you use the Attack action to grapple a creature,
the target takes 3 piercing damage if your grapple check succeeds.

For enemies who have resistance/immunity to "bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing from nonmagical attacks", would they still be damaged by the battlerager if the battlerager grappled them instead of attacking with a weapon? Here's what it says what the Grapple action is in the phb.

Grapple PHB p195
When you want to grab a creature or wrestle with it, you can use the
Attack action to make a special melee attack, a grapple. If you're
able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack
replaces one of them. The target of your grapple must be no more than
one size larger than you, and it must be within your reach.
Using at least one free hand, you try to seize the target by making a
grapple check, a Strength (Athletics) check contested by the target's
Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check (the target
chooses the ability to use). You succeed automatically if the target
is incapacitated. If you succeed, you subject the target to the
grappled condition (see the appendix). The condition specifies the
things that end it, and you can release the target whenever you like
(no action required).

The way I see it, while a grapple is a "Special Melee Attack", it is not an attack because it lacks an attack roll, instead being a check instead. Thus if a werewolf or similar creature with resistance/immunity to piercing was grappled by a Battlerager, they'd still take the full (If measly) 3 piercing damage, even if the Spiked Armor isn't silvered or magical.

@justhalf Please do not write answers in comments..

@ThomasMarkov I didn't bother to find source for my claims, so I didn't put it as an answer.

@justhalf Yes, and the linked meta discusses that: “ It is "cheating" by locking your answer to the top. Accepted answers or answers with higher scores should go to the top to indicate their quality. Bypassing that by sticking your answer in a comment on the question is unacceptable.
It bypasses all our quality control mechanisms: we can't downvote your "answer", edit it, or comment on it to request clarification or improvements. Answers also bump a question to the top so that people will scrutinize the answer; comments don't do this.”

Good points. Point taken.

It’s a (special) attack
Notwithstanding that grapples (and shoves) do not use an attack roll, they are explicitly attacks, and werewolves etc. are immune.
As the grapple rules say (emphases mine):

When you want to grab a creature or wrestle with it, you can use the Attack action to make a special melee attack, a grapple. If you're able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces one of them.


Your answer would be improved by citing the PHB passage that says that grapples are special attacks.

@kirt so it would. Why did you make it a comment rather than editing the answer?

I typically cold edit when I am fixing something that is clearly wrong.  Before adding something that I think improves a post, I usually look for agreement from the poster that it is an improvement, or tacit permission to edit.  For your posts specifically I am even more cautious about adding material, since you usually keep your rules answers as short as possible (although you run longer on gaming advice and personal dynamics).
